# Apache CXF 2.3.0 wsdl2java error Could not find jaxws21 frontend within classpath

Tags: java, cxf, wsdl2java

I want to generate web service client using Apache CXF 2.3.0 and jdk6. For parameter `-frontend jaxws21` I am getting error

> Could not find jaxws21 frontend within classpath

I even tried `-fe jaxws21`, but getting same error.

If I use jdk7 its works fine. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to a newer version of CXF.   2.3.0 is ancient and unsupported.  I don't think the jaxws21 flag was even added at that point.